# Why can't the following loop be parallelized?

Tags: c, openmp

```
double A[N] = { ... }, B[N] = { ... };

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
  A[i] = B[i] – A[i –1];
}
```

Why can't this loop be parallelized using the `#pragma omp parallel for` construct?

Comment: How would you expect it to be parallelized given that each iteration depends on the previous one (`A[i-1]`)?

Comment: I don't see where the problem is since it is a sm system. Can you maybe explain what the error would be ?

Comment: A parallelized loop still has to act like it would if it wasn't parallelized. For each `i`, the new value of `A[i]` depends on the *new* value of `A[i-1]`, not the original one (except for `i == 1`). There is no way to know what `A[i-1]` if without having already done iteration `i-1`. This is an innately serial operation.

Comment: Do you know _what parallelization is_? Try to describe it in one sentence by filling gaps: 'Parallelization is ______ the problem so that each _________ solved ______ from others'. Then see how / whether the last clause can be applied to your code.

Comment: You cannot trivially parallelize the loop using the OpenMP directive, but you *can parallelize this operation* using a different (much more complex) approach. See *parallel prefix sum* for more information.

Comment: @CiaPan Parallelizaiton is to divide the problem so that each part can be solved independetly from others ?

Comment: @ThomasJager: Re “There is no way to know what A[i-1] if without having already done iteration i-1. This is an innately serial operation.”: It is expressed as serial. It is not innately serial. Each A[i] can be expressed as functions of A[0] and B[i] prior to the operation, with no reference to any post-operation value of any A[i].

Comment: Precisely. Now, what about the last clause: 'each part can be solved independently from others'...? Whatever way to divide the problem you choose, there will exist some item `A[i]` in one part and `A[i-1]` in another one. And the former needs the latter to be calculated. In other words it depends on that, so they can _not_ be processed _independently_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is pretty plain in the code. To calculate `A[i]` you need to calculate `A[i-1]` first. There are `N` steps where every step depends on the previous step.

In general, a loop `for(int i=1; i<N; i++)` is suitable for parallelism if the loop would produce the exact same result if you changed the header to `for(int i=N-1; i>0; i--)`

Maybe that was a bit confusing. It has nothing to do with reverse order. The point is that you should be able to do each step individually.